# How to sync the colours of bootstrap btn.default and pagination controls?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I want to sync the colours for bootstrap's `pagination` and `btn.default` controls. But it's proving harder than I first thought.

The `pagination` section has 4 groups of 3, one group for each state:

```
@pagination-color:                     @link-color;
@pagination-bg:                        #fff;
@pagination-border:                    #ddd;

@pagination-hover-color:               @link-hover-color;
@pagination-hover-bg:                  @gray-lighter;
@pagination-hover-border:              #ddd;

@pagination-active-color:              #fff;
@pagination-active-bg:                 @brand-primary;
@pagination-active-border:             @brand-primary;

@pagination-disabled-color:            @gray-light;
@pagination-disabled-bg:               #fff;
@pagination-disabled-border:           #ddd;
```

But there are just 3 `btn` variables, with no mention of state :

```
@btn-default-color:              #333;
@btn-default-bg:                 #fff;
@btn-default-border:             #ccc;
```

I think the `btn` state colours are generated using a mixin like `darken()` or `lighten()`.

---

*Can anybody recommend a way to efficiently syncronise the colours of these controls?*

Ideally I'd like to add a new set of variables that can be inserted into the bootstrap variables file, something like this:

```
@btn-default-color:              @control-color;
@btn-default-bg:                 @control-bg;
@btn-default-border:             @control-border;
```

... and ...

```
@pagination-color:                     @control-color;
@pagination-bg:                        @control-bg;
@pagination-border:                    @control-border;

@pagination-hover-color:               @control-hover-color;
//... etc ...
```

But I am getting confused on the specifics, shifting variables around from one place to another :(

Comment: Well, yes, button state colors are [hardcoded](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/less/mixins/buttons.less#L6). So there's not much you can do except either of: A. sync pagination colors to button state colors (by using the same hardcoded `darken/lighten` mods as in `.button-variant` code). B. Override/replace button code with your own using your new button variables.

Comment: I feared that was the case. Ta for that.